# NP.Array extract between

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, extract

I have a Numpy array  which looks like the following:

```
array(['xsf (Parse EE1)', 'xxdsf (Parse E1A)',
   'sef(Parse E1A)'], dtype='<U36')
```

How can I keep the text between "Parse " and ")" and remove everything else so the results look like the following:

```
array(['EE1', 'E1A',E1A'], dtype='<U36')
```

Please note I am working with fairly large array and my overarching target is to extract the text between between "Parse " and ")".

Thanks in advance :)
Ed

Comment: Numpy doesn't have great string processing ability — the `Num` stands for numeric. If you did this Pandas you could use `extract()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed format you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with slicing

```py
ary = np.array(['xsf (Parse EE1)', 'xxdsf (Parse E1A)',
   'sef(Parse E1A)'], dtype='<U36')

np.array([x[-4:-1] for x in ary])
array(['EE1', 'E1A', 'E1A'], dtype='<U3')
```

Or Use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to get index of substring

```py
np.array([x[x.find('Parse ') + len('Parse '):x.find(')')] for x in ary])
array(['EE1', 'E1A', 'E1A'], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: Thanks mate - I tried it but it didn't work. It just returned blank array. I am actually working with a very large array.

Comment: try this `np.array([x[x.find('Parse ')+len('Parse '):x.find(')')] for x in ary])` Both work for me

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND - it worked like a charm
Thanks :)